# error server in login with volley com.android.volley.ServerError

Tags: android, api, android-volley, lumen

I have error in login with volley

> com.android.volley.ServerError
>   and Unexpected response code 500 for http://api.matraindonesia.com/login

```
private void Login(){

    String url = "http://api.matraindonesia.com/login";
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            if (response.trim().equals("success")){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Login Successfully!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Login Failed!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"this error:"+ error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("email",etEmail.getText().toString().trim());
            params.put("password",etPassword.getText().toString().trim());

            return super.getParams();
        }
    };
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Comment: The `Error 500 Internal server Error` means something wrong with the server. Check your server code please. I hope this helps

Comment: Code 500 means *Generic server error*. This could be caused by either the error in server software, or you misusing the API.